# Can you pass a file to a sap.ui.unified.FileUploader and call it manually?

Tags: sapui5

Suppose if I wanted to process an uploaded file in JavaScript and remove some entries from it could I process the file and then manually upload it from the code to a sap.ui.unified.FileUploader object?